# Global constant in python

Tags: python, global-variables, constants

I want to find an efficient way to define a constant value in a script called main and then to be able by changing this value from the main, the new value to be passed to a class for example. If I define the value with capitals, like

```
FLAG = 0
```

then I import it from the main in the class by

```
from main import FLAG
```

Is this an acceptable way?

Comment: Do you want to change the value at runtime?

Comment: Constants are constant... meaning un-changing. You say you want to change it's value... Also python doesn't support constants. That said, that's a prefered way to access a value across multiple scripts.

Comment: @NomadMonad I mean before run the main. If it is 1 I want to change something in a function of a class, otherwise no change.